# Undo sorting in Sublime

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm pretty new at Sublime text 3 and I accidentally hit F9 and then closed sublime and did not save. The problem is that when I reopened the file it was all in alphabetical order and I can't seem to restore the file. Is there a way to fix this? The file was a MAGMA file with code, so it is useless if its in alphabetical order.

Thank you

Comment: When you close Sublime Text, it will automatically save the current state of the file. You can try restoring a previous version by going to the file location in Windows Explorer, right clicking the file, select properties, and then click on the previous version tab. If there are any previous versions, you can revert to it. You could also try a System Restore as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had meant to say that you closed the file and it *did* save it. (Otherwise the changes would have been lost when you reopened the file.)

If, upon reopening it, undo doesn't do anything (and I wouldn't expect it to at the start of an editing session), I'm afraid there isn't anything you can do to retrieve an older version—not unless you have a backup or can somehow return to the source data.